# Nodal Analysis Newbie Question

Tags: circuit-analysis, nodal-analysis

[image: Question]

So I was solving some nodal analysis questions for practice and I can't figure out the equation for Node 2 at I2. The voltage at node 1 is V_A and Voltage at node 2 is V_B. A little side note is that I have taken all the currents as leaving the nodes.

My equation for node 1 is: $$-12mA+\frac{V_A-0}{51}+\frac{V_A-V_B}{470}=0$$
My equation for node 2 is: $$ \frac{V_B-V_A}{470}+\frac{V_B-0}{51}+{V_B}=0$$

The idea for the second node is that $$V_B = V_1$$ Would that be a correct assumption? If not what would be the equation for the current going to the right from Node 2 using Ohm's law? I have never solved any nodal analysis questions with external circuits.

Comment: Drop the /$V_B/$ in second equation (and set both equations  =0) and you have it.  Nothing connected to right so no current draw.

Comment: but isn't there an external circuit to the right with voltage V1? Also since I am solving it with the assumption that there is current leaving the node in 3 directions then what will I have for the right direction as zero does not make sense...

Comment: You don't sum up voltages in KCL. Change the second equation. There is no need for V_B. You cannot take Vb to be equal to V1.

Comment: You could connect any external circuit you want or none at all. The actual voltage at \$V_1\$ depends what that external circuit is. So you can't solve the circuit until you decide what it is. If your end goal is, for example, to find the Thevenin equivalent for this circuit, then you might be interested in finding the output voltage with no external circuit connected.

Comment: Thank you, everyone!

Comment: In your second equation what are the units for $$V_B$$? Rest of the terms have current units in both your equations. It is KCL you are applying after all.